# How to modify the text quantity and price each on stripe form?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

In the stripe form there is the summary of quantity and unit price:

[image]

I want to change the text below the total price to `Lot 1 of 5 units`. Here is how I passed data to stripe:

```php
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'line_items' => [
    [
      'price_data' => [
        'currency' => $currency,
        'product_data' => [
          'name' => token_symbol() . ' Token',                                                                              
        ],
        'unit_amount_decimal' => 100
      ],
      'quantity' => $token
    ]                                                                      
  ],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => route('payment.stripe.success'),
  'cancel_url' => route('payment.stripe.cancel')
]);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're trying to do? Do you want to signify that this item is one of 5 items available? What's in `$token` variable?

Comment: The user purchased many items, but I want to pack it into 1 lot. $token is the number of items purchased

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to replicate ?
[image]

You would need a Price with 'package pricing' for this.
However this pricing structure is not possible to get using the `price_data` constructor, you would need a pre-defined Price on your Stripe account and just use `'line_items'=>[['price':$price_id,...`.

Comment: Another thing you could use is the Product label, but it's not as good as you might expect it to be. If say you set 'lot of 5' as your Product label, then the Session will read 'Product Name (per lot of 5) - Qty 1, $10.00 each'. Same thing, can't use it with `product_data`.